# Spring Security User defined url intercepter

Tags: java, spring-security

I have implemented the spring security in my webapp.

Below is my security confile file:

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">

    <!-- enable use-expressions -->
    <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/admin**" access="Admin" />

        <!-- access denied page -->
    <access-denied-handler error-page="/403" />
        <form-login 
            login-page="/login" 
            default-target-url="/welcome" 
            authentication-failure-url="/login?error" 
            username-parameter="mobileno"
            password-parameter="staffpwd" />
        <logout logout-success-url="/login?logout"  />
      <csrf/>
    </http>

    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider>
            <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
          users-by-username-query=
            "select username,password, enabled from users where username=?"
          authorities-by-username-query=
            "select username, role from user_roles where username =?  " />
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

</beans:beans>
```

In the intercept url right now /admin url is allowed only to Admin role users. Now i have to add a new rule that if someone is not verified or if blocked then that user must not access the url. There are few more business logic based on db table calculations. so how do i configure these user defined url interceptors.

Its my first time to do spring security, Please suggest me how i can get this done.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <!-- static resource -->
    <intercept-url pattern="/403" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll" />

    <!-- only user with Admin role can access -->
    <intercept-url pattern="/admin**" access="hasRole('Admin')" />

    <!-- other urls should be authenticated -->
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isFullyAuthenticated()" />

    <!-- access denied page -->
    <access-denied-handler error-page="/403" />
    <form-login 
        login-page="/login" 
        default-target-url="/welcome" 
        authentication-failure-url="/login?error" 
        username-parameter="mobileno"
        password-parameter="staffpwd" />
    <logout logout-success-url="/login?logout"  />
    <csrf/>
</http>
```

> Now i have to add a new rule that if someone is not verified or if blocked then that user must not access the url.There are few more business logic based on db table calculations

If you need to implement more complex business, you should implement your own `UserDetailsService` or `AuthenticationProvider`

Comment: Thanks for reply. can you tell that if i create my own AuthenticationHandler than how do i use this in config. so that spring uses this file to intercept urls

Comment: you own `AuthenticationHandler`, do you mean to implement a Filter ? you can extend `AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter`, `OncePerRequestFilter`, `GenericFilterBean` or `Filter`, then put it to http config `<custom-filter ref="customerFilter" position="your position" />`